# Is there a way to push message (LINE app) when there is an edit at google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, chatbot

I don't really know much about coding and I'm doing a project creating Line chat bot that will alarm user (push message to user) when google sheet got edit at column I. Just being clear here I did this for my own entertainment and for school project. I used google script editor to write the code.

But I got error after using `UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push',options);`

it said **error code 400**  content {"message":"The request body could not be parsed as JSON (line: 1, column: 10)"} this still be the same after `"muteHttpExceptions": true`

I'd really appreciate some new Idea or solution for LINE push message when there is an edit in google sheet.

Here is the code! I created function pushMsg() to push message from chatbot to a LINE user (in this case I use my userid to push message to)

```
function pushMsg() {
  var usrId = "Uc2db25baf...";
  var url = 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push';
  var channel_access_token = "soEtz7raMUcVQDhlQ7ttFaqUyiktj0...";
  var postData = {
    "to": "U1426ccaa18df...",
    "messages" : [
      {
        "type" : "text",
        "text" : "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  };
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization" : "Bearer " + channel_access_token
    },
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(postData),
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log("code: " + result.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log("text: " + result.getContentText());
}
```

I think the issue is at `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);` 
I'm really new to this and not really at good english so sorry if I am not clear. please help I really need some advice. Thank you in advance!

**Update**

The expected result is code:200 but I got code:400 text: {"message":"Bad request"}

This is another version of code. I tried remove the JSON.stringify but still got error:

```
function pushMsg() {
  var usrId = "Uc2db25baf...";
  var url = 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push';
  var channel_access_token = "soEtz7raMUcVQDhlQ7ttFaqUyiktj0...";
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization" : "Bearer " + channel_access_token
    },
    "payload" : {
    "to": "U1426ccaa18df...",
    "messages" : [
      {
        "type" : "text",
        "text" : "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log("code: " + result.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log("text: " + result.getContentText());
}
```

I got error code:400 text: text: {"message":"The request body could not be parsed as JSON (line: 1, column: 10)"} this time.

So as far as I know the problem should be the authorization step right?
Here is the step that I did.

1. Create Line API
2. Create google sheet
3. Write the function onEdit(e) make it call pushMsg()
4. Deploy web app and put the link to webhook URL at messaging API
   Is there any step I missed which can result in the errors I got? Again thank you in advance!!

Comment: A 400 error usually means that the data that you send to an api is incorrect (validation error). Looking at the documentation: https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#send-push-message. It expects the payload to be json format. Due to your JSON.stringify, the payload will be a string (with the json data in there). Perhaps you could try to remove JSON.stringify. If that does not work I guess that the api expects a different payload data.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The issue seems to be that you are telling the endpoint that you are POSTing a JSON "payload". But your payload is not a JSON string yet.

Try changing your options object to:

```js
var options = { 
  ...,
  "payload":JSON.stringify({
    "to": "U1426ccaa18df...",
    "messages":[
        {"type":"text", "text":"Hello wor1"}
    ]
  }),
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Aerials . Now I got **error code 400** content `{"message":"Bad request"} ` What should I do?

Comment: try removing the trailing commas

Comment: `  
var channel_access_token = "soEtz7raMUcVQDhlQ7ttFaqUyiktj...";

var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization" : "Bearer " + channel_access_token
    },
    "payload" : JSON.stringify({
      "to": "U1426ccaa18df...",
      "messages":[
        {
          "type":"text",
          "text":"Hello wor1"
        }
      ]
    }),
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };` Am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes, it looks alright, you should update your question. I would suggest though, removing from the original post everything except the [minimal-part-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) required to debug what is failing, in this case all that's unrelated to that UrlFetchApp can be removed IMHO. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. I already edited the question. and just an update I'm still stuck at error code 400 content {"message":"Bad request"}

Comment: I see. Your `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` request looks alright. The error is coming from the API.  I would try authenticating the request first, and then once that hurdle is passed, configure the body of the request so that it can be accepted.